# Ansible returns 'AnibleUnicode' instead of JSON, unable to filter

Tags: list, filter, ansible, output, json-query

I'm unable to filter the following output with `json_query`, even though it works on a jmespath validator website.

Let me explain in detail with the code.

`type_debug` returns `AnsibleUnicode` for **members** value, so when I tried to use `json_query` to filter output it returned `null`. I need to get value from key `ip`, but I don't know how to do it in a good way.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
   - RPN:
      stdout:  >-
              "members": [
              {
                "id": 0,
                "ip": "x.x.x.x",
                "owner": "buzut",
                "private_ip": "10.91.154.39",
                "speed": 100,
                "status": "active"
              }
              ]

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ RPN.stdout | type_debug }}"
```

Comment: I dont see your playbook about jmepath? And your json is not valid

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand that you like to gather all member with a `json_query`. To do so I've corrected the JSON slightly.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    RPN:
      stdout: >-
              {
                "members": [{
                  "id": 0,
                  "ip": "x.x.x.x",
                  "owner": "buzut",
                  "private_ip": "10.91.154.39",
                  "speed": 100,
                  "status": "active"
                }]
              }

  tasks:

  - name: Show type(s)
    debug:
      msg:
        - "{{ RPN.stdout             | type_debug }}"
        - "{{ RPN.stdout | from_json | type_debug }}"
        - "{{ RPN.stdout |   to_json | type_debug }}"

  - name: Show members
    debug:
      msg: "{{ RPN.stdout | from_json | json_query('members') }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show type(s)] *********
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - AnsibleUnicode
  - dict
  - str

TASK [Show members] *********
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - id: 0
    ip: x.x.x.x
    owner: buzut
    private_ip: 10.91.154.39
    speed: 100
    status: active
```

> *I need to get value from key `ip`*

```yaml
 - name: Show value of key 'ip'
    debug:
      msg: "{{ RPN.stdout | from_json | json_query('members[*].ip') }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show value of key 'ip'] *********
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - x.x.x.x
```

**Further Documentation**

- [Selecting JSON data: JSON queries](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries)